# DBT(Data Build Tools) - drop the default database prefix that gets added to each model on deployment

Tags: database, data-modeling, azure-synapse, dbt, fishtown-analytics

In DBT, whenever we deploy the models, the database name gets prefixed to each deployed model in the sql definition in database.

I need to configure the dbt project in a way that it doesn't prefix database name to the deployed models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite the built-in `ref` macro. This macro returns a `Relation` object, so we can manipulate its output like this:

```py
{% macro ref(model_name) %}

    {% do return(builtins.ref(model_name).include(database=false)) %}

{% endmacro %}
```

So, from there, all models that use the `ref` function will return the `Relation` object without the `database` specification.

```py
dbt code:
select * from {{ ref('model') }}

compiled code:
select * from schema_name.model
```

#### EDIT:

As you requested, here's an example to remove the database name from the sources:

```py
{% macro source(source_name, table_name) %}

    {% do return(builtins.source(source_name, table_name).include(database=false)) %}

{% endmacro %}
```

I've worked with sources from different databases, so if you ever get to that case, you might want to edit the macro to offer an option to include the database name, for example:

```py
{% macro source(source_name, table_name, include_database = False) %}

    {% do return(builtins.source(source_name, table_name).include(database = include_database)) %}

{% endmacro %}
```

```
dbt code:
select * from {{ source('kaggle_aps', 'coaches') }}
select * from {{ source('kaggle_aps', 'coaches', include_database = True) }}

compiled code:
select * from schema_name.object_name
select * from database_name.schema_name.object_name
```

More details can be found in the [official documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/builtins)

Comment: while this is helpful in removing the database name from the generated models, but I am still seeing this three part naming convention with the sources. Is it possible to remove the database name from the sources as well.

Comment: yeap, you can do the same using the `builtins.source`. I'll edit my answer with the code snippet.

Comment: [A comment was just posted as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76970129/5211833): "While this works for removing database_name from the models and the sources as well, there is still a problem left.

While running the tests using the dbt test command, the default database_name ("" in my case) still creates a problem leading to PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR. The table name appears like this - .schema_name.table_name

Error: [PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '.': extra input '.'"

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that:

1. You don't want the schema name with a prefix added to it, like just be `finance.modelname` instead of `dbname_finance.modelname`, or
2. you want the relation name to be rendered with a two-part name (`schema.modelname`) instead of the three-part name (`database.schema.modelname`)?

If #1, I recommend you read the entire [custom schema names docs page](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-schemas), specifically the part about [Advanced custom schema configuration](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/using-custom-schemas)

If it's #2, this is a change required at the adapter level. Since you've tagged `synapse`, I'd wager a guess that you're using Synapse SQL Serverless Pools because I have also encountered the fact that you can't use three-part names in Serverless pools. Last week, I actually made [dbt-synapse-serverless](https://github.com/dbt-msft/dbt-synapse-serverless) a separate adapter from dbt-synapse which in fact disables the three-part name.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! It is the #2 scenario that I am talking about in my question. Yes I am using Azure synapse, I am not sure if it is serverless or not , will have to check for that. Will keep you posted on my findings.

Comment: This is not working as we are using dedicated SQL pool. Is there any other solution I can follow to solve this problem for dedicated SQL pool in Azure Synapse.

Comment: @user961 can you please provide an example of the error you get? This is news to me that three-part names not being supported in dedicated pool. Are you trying to work on the master db?

Comment: I think there is some confusion. So I am already getting the three-part names in the dedicated pool but I want the two part names convention in the dedicated pools. Can you please guide me on how to achieve that i.e. two part naming convention in dedicated pool when deploying using DBT using dbt run command. We want the models to be deployed as schemaname.modelname

Comment: Can you suggest me some solution/workaround for the scenario I mentioned in the above comment. Thanks

Comment: Headed to bed now. But I think I can make a new branch of dbt-synapse that might help you tmw. Stay tuned

Comment: sure..looking forward to it..

Comment: ok can you try installing [this branch](https://github.com/dbt-msft/dbt-synapse/pull/66) using `pip install git+https://github.com/dbt-msft/dbt-synapse.git@no_dbname` and let me know if that fixes things?

Comment: This is not helping either. This one is also rendering the model with three part naming convention. can we try something else?

Comment: Also, I wanted to understand that there is not much documentation around DBT, and I mostly have to clarify my doubts or put my questions on stackoverflow. Is it not a widely used tool? This process makes me highly dependent on stackoverflow to be able to proceed on my work.

Comment: 1. let's move this discussion over to the relevant [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dbt-msft/dbt-synapse/issues/65)
2. the vast majority of product support for dbt happens in the [dbt slack](https://www.getdbt.com/community/join-the-community). you should join! I already have a thread there w/ your coworker Avi.
3. dbt is widely used (outside of MSFT) but less so at w/ MSFT dbs
4. dbt-synapse in particular is an open-source plugin largely maintained by me and my team.
5. your ask is new enhancement that isn't supported today. I'm on vacation right now, but looking into it for you anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts on taking up this enhancement just for us. This really means a lot and I am looking forward to it. Have a great vacation till then!!